# Is there a minimum Android version for supporting inappbrowser?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

Our Phonegap app using inappbrowser works really well on every device tested except one using Android version 4.3 where the CSS seems unresponsive and the onscreen keyboard doesn't pop up when you tap in text fields.  I can't seem to find any documentation on minimum versions of Android for supporting the various Phonegap plugins.

Comment: Current versions of all the core plugins support android 4 and greater. Some of them will probably support even previous versions. The CSS problems aren't cordova's fault, old android versions include old webview with less HTML5 features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, I've used phonegap a far as Android 2.1 . The problem you could have on such older versions is the phonegap version.

You should provide further information such as phonegap version.

But I can assure you that Android 4.3 has a very broad support for all Phonegap/Cordova 5+ plugins.

If I were you I wolud try updating phonegap version according to your desire of minimum Android version you want your app to be executed on.

For example, until Android 2.3 on inappbrowser apps it wasn't able to use overflow scroll, so you had to use an external plugin to get that effect, which was really annoying.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I find out which version of Phonegap is optimal for Android 4.3?

Comment: You can use the newer stable version.

Comment: I already have Phonegap 5.4.0 installed.  When I go to update, it doesn't, suggesting that 5.4.0 is the newer stable version.

Comment: I think 6.0 is up but it's not set as stable yet

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to diagnose, but it might be a browser issue: Android 4.3 does not necessarily ship with Chrome, so it might be still running the old "Android Browser", which does not support all (CSS-)features Chrome supports. [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) helps to find out if a browser supports a certain feature.

If it's indeed a browser issue and you have to support older browsers like the Android Browser, you might want to check out [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). It provides a recent version of Chrome as a WebView and as InAppBrowser with consistent behaviour on all Android 4.x devices. Downside: Your app's size will increase...

If it's not the browser you might need to show us some of your code.

Comment: I'm not sure that the code would reveal much.  It's just inappbrowser pointing to a URL.  I asked our QA guy whether Chrome is installed and it is.  Furthermore, I ran our app on Amazon's Device Farm on a real Samsung Note II running Android 4.3 and, sure enough, the CSS is off in a way that it isn't in later versions of Android.